# Token validation failing in PCF but validating in local

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, okta, pcfdev

I have secured an API using okta. In order to call the API one need to generated the Bearer token and call the API. These all things are fine in my local..

But when I deployed this secured API service PCF , and calling this secured Api from local (passing bearer token in header) its resulting in an error.

Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Invalid token"

Comment: It is difficult to answer your questions without some details. Can you share following details?
1. Which authorization server are you using?
2. If you decode the token on jwt.io, can you paste the token contents?

Answer (score 1):

Need to setup Proxy. After setting up proxy its working fine